# Как отформатировать время HH:MM

Tags: c++

Подскажите как получить минуты с 0 если минуты < 10?

```
SYSTEMTIME st;
    GetLocalTime(&st);
std::cout << st.wHour << ":" << st.wMinute;
```

Допустим время на часах 22:03, то я получаю 22:3 - а не 22:03

Comment: Кроме виндовых есть и стандартные способы получения времени (на случай переноса на другие платформы, и вообще, для красоты).

Answer (score 5):

```
cout << fill('0') << setw(2) << st.wMinute;
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать [`printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) и модификатор `%02d`:

```
printf("%02d:%02d", st.wHour, st.wMinute);
```

[Ideone](https://ideone.com/sEd3U4)

Comment: вроде принг устарел

Comment: @Sector32 устарел, не устарел, но в данном случае код с `printf` получается приятней (имхо)